# Is disabling sudo password prompt a security risk?

Tags: passwords, sudo

I was reading the [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password/443071#443071) over on Ask Ubuntu and they suggest adding the following line to `etc/sudoers` so that you're not prompted to enter your password each time you run `sudo`

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Is this a security risk and if so, what are some ways people can exploit this?

Comment: Yes, it's a security risk, but if somebody gains access to an account of the `admin` group, you're already in trouble. It's rather easy to create an alias that executes malicious code that will be executed the instead of the actual `sudo` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How secure is NOPASSWD in passwordless sudo mode?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45712/how-secure-is-nopasswd-in-passwordless-sudo-mode)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it's a risk.  Anyone who touches your keyboard can get root access by running `sudo` and not worrying about your password. Anyone who has an exploit that gets them userland access can instantly get root access using the `sudo` command. This reduces isolation and increases the effort to recover from an attack or intrusion.

Comment: Good thing this is isn't done by default on the world's most used VPS.......  oh, wait...

Comment: @BillyC. which VPS is that?

Comment: Amazon..... EC2.......

Comment: Do we know if AWS provided any justification for this? They don't take security lightly so I suppose there must be some reason they've done it this way..